# Is there a way to instruct sonar scanner to exclude issues related with legacy code?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I want sonar scanner to run on a legacy project but capture only new issues. Is there a way to mark and neglect all the existing legacy issues ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can exclude those files from scan.

From project settings you can exclude, you can choose to exclude only for issues or you can totally exclude the file (no metrics is generated - loc, complexity, duplication nothing is calculated)

If first analysis has not happened use provisioning to achieve the same.

**Updating to cover peculiar case of excluding only old issues:**
By marking all old issues as false positives you'd exclude them from future analysis, though might sound like bonkers it will work as long as don't change directory structure.

Comment: The case is different. I don't want to exclude old files. I want to only exclude old issues. If any new codes are written on the old files, then issues with new codes in those old files should be reported but old issues in those files should not show up. I googled up to know about sonarqube differential views. But, I'm searching for any other options. But, thanks for attempting to answer.

Comment: Mark them as false positives then

Comment: Let me give it a try on making them as false positives, and shall come back here with my results. Thanks!

Comment: I resolved this issue by bulk changing status of those issues into 'Won't fix' ones. Also, sonarqube differential views are useful to see through changes between different versions of source code. Thanks @Shiva for the pointing out the idea of marking them as 'false positives'.

Comment: Before closing this question may I ask you if there is a similar idea for neglecting legacy code coverage too ? I have a project with nearly 1 lakh lines of codes. Out of which only 5% of codes have unit tests within it. My aim is to configure sonarque coverage report in a way that it should report coverage analysis only on the new lines of code. Right now it says 95% is not covered. It should neglect that unit tests aren't available for 95% of code. But, report coverage only among the new lines of code.

Comment: I just realized that differential view on coverage report with help of SCM activity changesets could fit the above requirements.